Help me to check poof of inequality: $\frac{1}{1-x} \leq e^{x+x^{2} \ln D}$ for all $0<x<1-\frac{1}{D}$, where $D\ge 2$ is a positive integer
Could you help me to check my proof for proving the following inequality? or any idea for better another proof!
Let $D\ge 2$ be a positive integer. For all $0<x \leq 1 - 1 / D$, the following inequality holds
$$\frac{1}{1 - x} \leq e^{x + x^{2} \ln D}$$
My effort: Taking the logarithm of both sides, the inequality to be proven is equivalent to
$
-\ln (1-x) \le x+x^2\ln D.
$
Let $ g(x) = -\ln (1-x) -(x+x^2\ln D) $. We need to show that $ g(x) \leq 0 $ for $ 0 < x \leq 1 - 1 / D $. We compute the first and second derivatives:
[
\begin{aligned}
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{1-x}-1-2x\ln D, \\
g''(x) &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-2 \ln D =\frac{x^2 (-2\ln D ) +  x (4\ln D) +1-2\ln D}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{aligned}
]
Solving the equation $ g''(x) = 0 $, we find the roots $ x_{1,2} = 1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\ln D}} $. By analyzing the sign of the derivative, we see that $ g'(x) $ is decreasing in the interval $ (0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\ln D}}] $ and increasing in $ [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\ln D}}, 1-\frac{1}{D}] $ (since $ D > 2\ln D $). We have $ g'(0)=0 $, $ g'(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\ln D}})=-3 $, and $ g'(1-1/D)= D-1-2\ln D + \frac{2\ln D}{D} = (D-1)(1-\frac{2\ln D}{D}) <0 $. Therefore, $ g'(x)\leq 0 $ for $ 0 < x \leq 1 - 1 / D $. Consequently, the function $ g(x) $ is decreasing in $ 0 < x \leq 1 - 1 / D $. Finally, we see that $ g(0) = 0 $, and $g(1-1/D) = -\ln D -(1-1/D)-(1-1/D)^2\ln D <0$. Thus, we have $g(x)\le 0$ for  $ 0 < x \leq 1 - 1 / D $.

For $D=2$, $\frac{1}{1 - x} \leq e^{x + x^{2} \ln D}$ does not seem correct.

See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgfrvpf9xv

$D=2; x = 0.49$ is a counterexample: $
1.961 \simeq \frac{1}{1-0.49}  = \frac{1}{1-x} \color{red}{\geq} e^{x+x^{2} \ln D} = e^{0.49+0.49^{2} \ln 2} \simeq 1.92789...
$
